# Importing 3D models into webots 2023a and splitting parts into shapes for a robot

Tags: webots

I am quite new with Webots. I am wondering if there is a possibility to import 3D models into Webots 2023a as it was possible within Webots 2021b. I have managed to import it within 2021b, but when I specify the bounding object and I apply physics, the robot falls through the arena and bounces around underneath. The same thing occurs when I just create a solid with a box shape and apply bounding object and physics to it.

I know that you can import it using a CADshape within the 2023a version, would I have to import all parts of my model assembly separately and then assemble it within Webots under a robot node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to merge together in your 3D modeling software all the parts of your robots that don't move with respect to each other and save them into a single Collada/DAE or a wavefront/OBJ CAD file. At the end you will have several CAD files corresponding to each moving part of your robot that you will assemble together in Webots within a [Robot](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot) node using the [CADShape](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/cadshape) node. For example in case of a simple differential wheels robots, you will have typically 3 CAD files: one for the base of the robot and one for each of the two wheels. For a legged robot, you will end up with many more CAD files.

As for the bounding objects, I would recommend against using CAD files for them as it will impact the performance and quality of collision detection. Instead, you should use primitives, such as [Sphere](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/sphere), [Capsule](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/capsule), [Box](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/box), [Cylinder](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/cylinder) and/or combination of them as explained in [this tutorial](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-5-compound-solid-and-physics-attributes).

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*

Comment: Thank you for the answer and recommendations, that clears it up.